# Multi-Line Text Box vs Single Line Text Box

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-research, text, textbox

We have a 'Notes' section in several of our webpages that is currently only displayed as a single line text box. We tend to get short responses (5-7 words) describing what they need. This almost always results in the need for a follow up before any action can be taken.

Would providing a Multi-Line text box lead the user to believe that we were looking for a more robust (see: lengthy) response? I'm basing this solely on intuition so if there is any research for or against this thought I'd love to know about it.

Comment: Please see https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72901/does-the-height-of-an-input-field-affect-ux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the height of an input field affect UX?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/72901/does-the-height-of-an-input-field-affect-ux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always explain what you expect from your user to answer in order to decrease the need for a follow-up and put a limit to their answer (Something like a 0/300 characters at the right bottom corner of the text area)

Comment: I wish. This is an ask from Marketing for an internal application. Our tech support teams get tickets and then fill out this multipage form that details everything that they have done. The Marekting team wants better "stories." Telling the techs to type more wont help. So Im trying to find a way to both make Marketing happy and reduce the amount of user education and follow up. Although the character limit indicator is a great idea.

Comment: Hmm, I see. So you need a better solution for inter-departmental communication, i.e. how can tech support provide more valuable information to marketing. The obvious solution here would be the good old form. Have marketing come up with a format of the "stories" they need, and this way tech support will know what info to provide. A big blank form with "Type your story" won't help much. Have a meeting with Marketing and ask for a format template with what they need.